# Enlarging the space $PC(a,b)$ to include functions with one or more infinite singularities

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, continuity, orthonormal, orthogonality

I'm reading a Fourier analysis book and on the chapter about convergence and completeness of orthogonal sets of functions I have one part which I don't understand. I have uploaded the part as an image and highlighted the relevant parts in the text:

[image]

What I'm interested about is the purple part (the other colored boxes are there to just give more info). My question is:

> Why can one enlarge the space $PC(a,b)$ to include functions as in the
>   example in the image by simply allowing improper integrals in the definition of the
>   inner product and the norm for functions in $PC(a,b)?$ This in
>   unclear for me, can someone make this more specific? Example?

Thank you for any help! Please let me know if you need more information or if the image is unclear. I tried to give  all the needed information in the image.

P.S.

To enlarge the image do: right click --> show image / open image in new tab.

Comment: Does anybody have any ideas? Is my question too unclear? =)

Comment: Hallo jjepsuomi! :) It seems to me that you are dealing with piecewise cont. functions. The vector space of piecewise cont. functions is not a Banach space as shown in the attached reference (it is not a complete normed space). If one allows for functions like $f(x)=x^{-1/4}$ in the example to overcome non completeness, then one moves away from the original $PC(a,b)$: which is the "extended" vector space with the improper integrals the text is referring to?

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help @Avitus =) You are correct, I'm dealing with piecewise cont. functions. Okay, I think I got it :) Appreciate it!

Comment: I am interested in the new vector space containing piecewise cont. functions and functions with unbounded discontinuity points like $f(x)=x^{-1/4}$ at $x=0$: if you want you could introduce it in your OP, so people can answer to your question in some detail

Comment: +1 Sorry @Avitus for my late reply. So umm, I didn't quite follow? You mean I should ask about the vector space containing piecewise cont. functions and functions with unbounded discontinuity points? =)

Comment: I thought you were interested in the "enlarged" space. Am I wrong? Are you interested on the change in the inner product / norm, instead?

Comment: Yes I'm interested in the "enlarged" space :) I was confused by the sentence: "It is easy enough to enlarge the space $PC(a,b)$ to include functions with one or more infinite regularities in the interval $(a,b)$". I guess this whole part in the book was confusing to me, I didn't quite get the idea of the "enlarged" space and was asking if someone could say the point in other words etc. =) Why does the author introduce the "enlarged" space? Why not just stick with $PC(a,b)$? =) Sometimes I miss the point totally :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $PC(a,b)$ of piecewise continuous functions (p.c. functions) on the interval $[a,b]$ is not complete; this is the content of the example in the left picture in the OP. The definition of p.c. functions is given on the top right picture in the OP: we note that an element of $PC(a,b)$ can have a finite number of "jumps" and all of them must be finite.

How to achieve completeness? 
The author tried to enlarge $PC(a,b)$ with functions $f$ admitting

1. non finite jumps (like $f(x)=x^{-\frac{1}{4}})$ for $x>0$ and  $f(0)=0$ in the example)
2. absolute converging integral, i.e.

$$\int_a^b |f(x)|dx <\infty $$

Let us call this space $PC_\infty(a,b)$; it contains the original $PC(a,b)$.
The enlarged space $PC_\infty(a,b)$ admits the same scalar product defined on $PC(a,b)$ (due to absolute convergence of elements of $PC_\infty(a,b)$ );  the integral can be improper though, as shown in

$$\langle f, 1 \rangle := \int_0^1\frac{1}{x^\frac{1}{4}}dx:=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+} \int_t^1\frac{1}{x^\frac{1}{4}}dx$$

where we considered $PC_\infty(0,1)$ and $f$ given as in the example in the OP. With $1$ we mean the constant function $g(x)=1$ on $[0,1]$.
The result of the scalar product $\langle f, 1\rangle$ is finite!

The problem is that even $PC_\infty(a,b)$ is not large enough to be complete: this is the meaning of the  paragraph in the violet box in the left picture of the OP.

Comment: +1 Thank you @Avitus you are great, as always ;D